# how to handle status 401 with axios in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

i want to check if user is authorized or not , in my AuthContext

```
import React, {createContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import AuthService from '../Services/AuthService';
export const AuthContext = createContext();
export default ({ children })=>{
const [user,setUser] = useState(null);
const [isAuthenticated,setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
const [isLoaded,setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{
    AuthService.isAuthenticated()
    .then(data =>{
        setUser(data.user);
        setIsAuthenticated(data.isAuthenticated);
        setIsLoaded(true);
    })
    
},[]);

return (
    <div>
        {!isLoaded ? <h1>Loading</h1> : 
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user,setUser,isAuthenticated,setIsAuthenticated}}>
            { children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>}
    </div>
)
}
```

and in Auth service i got this :

```
const Axios = require("axios");
export default{

isAuthenticated : ()=>{
    return  Axios({
        url: "http://localhost:4000/user/authenticated",
        method: "GET",
        
    }).then(res=>{
                if(res.status !== 401)
                    return res.json().then(data => data);
                else
                    return res.json({
                        isAuthenticated : false, 
                        user:{
                            firstName:" ",
                            lastName:" ",
                            email:" "}});
            })
      .catch(err=>console.log("authenticated error :"+err));
}

}
```

i got error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

11 | useEffect(()=>{

12 |     AuthService.isAuthenticated()

13 |     .then(data =>{

14 |         setUser(data.user); // Error

15 |         setIsAuthenticated(data.isAuthenticated);

16 |         setIsLoaded(true);

17 |     })

i test it in postman and i got what i expected

Answer (score 0):

Just return the object instead of calling res.json

```
                return {
                    isAuthenticated : false, 
                    user:{
                        firstName:" ",
                        lastName:" ",
                        email:" "}};
```

Comment: i got the same error : Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: Console.log(data) above the setUser(data.user);  to see what the object looks like. Maybe you need to do data.data.user

Comment: i got  data :undefined